# COB token transfer failed with error: "Bad Instruction"; will I get my tokens back?

Tags: tokens, contract-debugging, erc-20

I transferred 10 COB tokens from my one address `0x782e265f911167e4FDbfbFb63a32cC27341724E7` on my Metamask wallet to another Metamask wallet address `0x0a42AD94FC81db989575365Be28DCd64417Ce564` but the transaction (TXHash: `0x195698e304112a6b1c4f5f3879c6ab796d7d1165550018250557ad73e7fd4d0a` did not go through properly and returned error:

> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]

Even though the transaction history shows that the transaction was successful (see screenshot below), my transaction had failed. Failed [transaction is here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x195698e304112a6b1c4f5f3879c6ab796d7d1165550018250557ad73e7fd4d0a):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you say, this transaction tried to transfer 10 tokens from from address 0x782e265f911167e4fdbfbfb63a32cc27341724e7 to address 0x0a42ad94fc81db989575365be28dcd64417ce564.

As far as I can tell, the transaction failed because the balance of address 0x782e... was zero at the time. So nothing happened, nothing was transferred, and I'm not sure what you are hoping to get back.

The balance of 0x0a42ad94fc81db989575365be28dcd64417ce564 currently stands at 5720.010000000000000000 COB; I don't know if that's what you expect or not.

Comment: There's an almost identical transaction at the same time [0xb5b3a1eb.. (Dec-03-2017 01:20:04 AM +UTC)](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb5b3a1eb66d05d2520a740ad2cf559c6c029bdcad5cd59b56575bc0d7b1ad0ac) that was successful.

Comment: Yes, that transaction at block 4665433 cleared out account 0x782e... This was three blocks before the transaction in the question.  By the time of the failed transaction (block 4665436), account 0x782e... was empty. That's why the transaction failed.